# Store class type as a variable to identify next expected object type in list in java

Tags: java, class, types

I'm working on a project where I obtain a list of strings and need to parse them into objects of different types, for example I have `Command`, `FloatArgument` and `IntegerArgument` as 3 different classes. For a given input like "fetch 5 3.45" I need to see if it is correct and then get the arguments. For this I decided to ceate a sort of library where all commands can be stored in a hashlist

```
baseCommands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
```

In the command class I store basic information I need for each command and I'd also like to include the next expected token as for now I'm pretty sure for each command there is only going to be 1 type of token which can follow any command/argument. Therefor I created a `Class` field inside the command class as well as the argument classes which stores this information:

```
public class Command {
    public int identifier;
    public Class next;
    public boolean isLast;

    public Command(int identifier, Class next, boolean isLast) {
        //add the stuff neccesary to make general commands. (except string name).
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.next = next;
        this.isLast = isLast;
    }
}
```

Normally, as I understand it, if you would use an abstract class for storing different class types if they are all similar. For example an abstract class Animal is extended by `Dog`, `Cat`, etc. However in this case I have 2 separate things: Commands and Arguments. I feel like having an empty abstract class might not be the most elegant solution here, but I could be wrong.

As I understand it the Class field is used to store class types. This would be ideal so that later I can see for a given token in an input if the next token after it matches the expected one by simply doing the following:

```
token.type instanceof lastToken.next
```

However once I try to put information into the hashmap like this:

```
baseCommands.put("execute", new Command(1, Command, false));
```

I get the following simple error:

> Command cannot be resolved to a variable

Now I know that what it's trying to do is to pass a variable that doesn't exist instead of the class type like I'm trying to do. How can I pass the class Command as a type instead? Will I be able to use the above mentioned method of checking if the next token in the input is correct? Is this a correct way of doing this or should I create another abstract class for both commands and arguments?

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to Command.class:

```
baseCommands.put("execute", new Command(1, Command.class, false));
```